# How to inherit or orverride @classmethod in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

I want to inherit `@classmethod` of `class BaseModel(object)`

How to inherit or override the `@classmethod` in our custom module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this today :)

You can extend it in a couple of ways. It depends if you really need to extend `BaseModel` or if you need to extend a specific sub class of `BaseModel`.

**Sub Class**

For any sub class you can inherit it as you would normally:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class User(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.users'

    @classmethod
    def check(cls, db, uid, passwd):
        return super(User, cls).check(db, uid, passwd)
```

**Extend BaseModel Directly**

In the case of `BaseModel` itself you are going to need to monkey patch:

```
from odoo import models

def my_build_model(cls, pool, cr):
    # Make any changes I would like...

    # This the way of calling super(...) for a monkey-patch
    return models.BaseModel._build_model(pool, cr)

models.BaseModel._build_model = my_build_model
```